# Downvoted for answering an unclear question

Tags: discussion

The OP posted a question showing results from his script but not the actual script.

I attempted to add a comment to his question, which was after he posted a reply about an error he kept getting. However, being a low reputation I wasn't unable to do so, therefore I provided an answer to the error he was receiving.

From the comments the OP attempted my original suggestion then replied to my post, only after then he posted his whole script. I looked at it that time and replied with more specific information.

[Python: How to store for loop result in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736058/python-how-to-store-for-loop-result-in-a-list/30736416#30736416)

Is attempting to help with the original information provided reason to get downvoted, even though I wasn't able to add a comment due to my reputation?

Comment: _"I wasn't able to add a comment due to my reputation?"_ That's still not a reason you circumvent the system, and post comments as answers. Just gain the rep to comment, it's not much you need.

Comment: Nice edit. Does Python support multiline statements? If so, edit and wrap that long line so it doesn't scroll horizontally.  That's always nice.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm not sure how to wrap the code without adding a line (enter) myself.

Comment: @Leb That's how you'd do it- Adding a new line. That's why Will asked if Python supports multiline statements. You should only make it wrap if it would be correct in the code itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm going to speculate here, but I think you were down voted because the answer is low quality. Your answer boils down to:

> Convert it to a list, here's a link.

That's low quality. It is, technically, an answer, but you don't explain how to do anything. Instead, you point the user to another site.

The answer you provided in the comments is better. Edit that into your answer. It contains both code and an explanation as to why the code works.

Comment: I do agree with you, but at first I had no information as to what his code was to even provide that as an answer.

Comment: An answer isn't the proper place to gather such information. If you need to get that information a comment is the correct way to ask for it. With your lower reputation, you aren't able to comment yet. You need to earn that via other actions (answering more clear questions, editing posts, asking questions). Using an answer as a comment to request more information is a good way to get down voted.

Comment: I did change my original answer to the one from the comment and that has made things clearer. Thank you.

Comment: @Leb now your edited answer says nothing about converting to a list...

Comment: I did another edit to reflect the change you suggested.

Answer (score 9):

Two things:

- Your answer wasn't a very good one.  At best, it said, "you need to do X, read this link."  Notwithstanding the fact that "go do X" without any explanation is confounding, if the link dies, your answer becomes very brittle.
- If the question is unclear, **don't answer it yet!**  You have to wait until the question becomes clear enough, or when you get enough reputation, you can comment on the question and ask for clarifying details.

Comment: I think your second point is important to stress. One doesn't have to answer every question one sees.